# Indirectly print the value of scalar variable - Tsql

Tags: sql-server

It seems a little nasty but I am wondering if it is possible. Actually I want to print values of several variables. I can write print statement multiple times but instead of this I am thinking to use a while loop and write one single statement that can print the values of all the variables one by one.

This is what I am thinking:

```
declare @test as nvarchar(4)
select @test  = 'test'

declare @test1 as int
select @test1 = 1234

print '@'+@test+'1'
```

the statement  `print '@'+@test+'1'` prints `@test1` which is OK. But what I am looking for is, if I can get the value of `@test1` using the same statement.

I hope so I am clear enough to say what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.  Variables are visible only within the declaration scope.  If you generate a variable name in code, a dynamic SQL statement will be needed to use.  The dynamic SQL statement runs in a different scope so the original variable is not available.  You could pass the value to the dynamic SQL statement as a parameter, but that would necessitate hard-coding the variable name.